# Why do I sometimes lose the scroll-event in my big table? Especially in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pagination, html-table

I'm developing a table component for big data, with automatic pagination in JavaScript. The component only create rows for the pages which are visible at the moment. When a page is not visible anymore, the component removes the rows.

All work's fine, expect the scrolling with the "page up" and "page down"-keys. Sometimes (especially in the Chrome browser) after the removePageContent-method was called, the scroll-event will not fire again. Only a click in the table can fix this temporary.

Here is a simplified example of my code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/STARSCrazy/xshs40Lo/16/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.fn.isOnScreen = function () {
    var win = $(".table-container").parent();  
    var vpTop = win.scrollTop();
    var vpLeft = win.scrollLeft();
    var vpRight = vpLeft + win.width();
    var vpBottom = vpTop + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();    
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
    
    return (!(vpRight < bounds.left || vpLeft > bounds.right || vpBottom < bounds.top || vpTop > bounds.bottom));
  };
  
  var createPageContent = function($page) {
      if (!$page.hasClass('hasContent'))
      {             
        var pageId = parseInt($page.attr("pageId"));
        var content = "";
        for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
          content = content + "<tr><td>" + (pageId * 100 + i) + "</td><td><div>value 2</div></td><td><div>value 3</div></td><td><div>value 4</div></td><td><div>value 5</div></td><td><div>value 6</div></td><td><div>value 7</div></td></tr>";         
        }
        $page.find(".placeholder").replaceWith(content);        
        $page.addClass('hasContent')
      }
  };
  
  var removePageContent = function($page) {
    if ($page.hasClass('hasContent')) {
     console.log("removePageContent");
     $page.removeClass('hasContent')
      $page.find("tr").remove();
      $page.append("<tr class='placeholder'></tr>");      
    }
  };  

  $(".table-container").scroll(function() {
   console.log("trigger scroll-event");
    var bodies = $("tbody");
    for (var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
      var $elem = $(bodies[i])     
      if ($elem.isOnScreen()) {
    createPageContent($elem);
      } else {
       removePageContent($elem);      
      }    
    }  
  });

 //Create 50 pages
 var pagesHtml = "";
 for(var iPage = 0; iPage < 50; iPage++) {
   pagesHtml = pagesHtml + "<tbody pageId='" + iPage + "'><tr class='placeholder'></tr></tbody>";
  }
  $("table").append(pagesHtml);

 //Initialize page 0
 var page0 = $(".table-container").find("tbody[pageId='0']");
  createPageContent(page0);
});
```

```css
.table-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

tr.placeholder {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='table-container'>
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th><th>Title 3</th><th>Title 4</th><th>Title 5</th><th>Title 6</th><th>Title 7</th></tr></thead>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width: 400px; padding: 20px;">
Please click into the table and then press down and hold the <b>"page down"-key</b>. Sometimes the browser don't fire the scroll-event again (mostly after 'removePageContent' is called). Especially in the Chrome-Browser. It's strange but with the Chrome-CPU-Profiler running, it works. Any ideas?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem: I add **tabIndex='100'** to the table-Element and now the browser can focus it again.

```
<table tabIndex='100'></table>
```

I found this interesting note in a [focus documentation](http://help.dottoro.com/ljpkdpxb.php).